# Will the "Too many requests" ban last longer next time you receive it?

Tags: support, ip-ban

I just got the "Too many requests" ban on Stack Exchange, which lasts about 5 minutes. I'm still trying to avoid the ban again, but I do still worry the next time I receive the ban, it would last a little longer.

**Does the "Too many requests" ban last longer next time I receive it?**

Comment: In my experience, no. But the details are undisclosed. By the way, if I may ask, are you using IE11 on Windows 8.1?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog No, not even using Windows 8.1.